# What is the smallest set of letters that can spell any integer?

Tags: english, formation-of-numbers, letters

Today my 9-year-old nephew told me that he can spell any integer in English using only 9 letters. This is how he's doing it:

```
    ...
-3: MINUS ONE MINUS ONE MINUS ONE
-2: MINUS ONE MINUS ONE
-1: MINUS ONE
 0: ONE MINUS ONE
 1: ONE
 2: ONE PLUS ONE
 3: ONE PLUS ONE PLUS ONE
    ...
```

The letters he's using are `E`, `I`, `L`, `M`, `N`, `O`, `P`, `S` and `U`.

Can we do better and spell any integer with less than nine letters? I think so!

Just please be sure to briefly explain any maths you are using in your method, so that my young nephew (and his uncle) can understand.

Comment: Well, the obvious (probably invalid because of missing brackets) answer would be to just use `MINUS MINUS` instead of `PLUS`, resulting in 7 characters.

Comment: It'd be interesting if other languages could be allowed.

Comment: [I,V,X,L,C,D,M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) - no negatives though.

Comment: Of course, the question taken literally as asked can be done with eight letters - to spell the literal phrase (A N Y I T E G R).  Granted, that's not what it meant to ask (and the answers are good)...but my interpretation isn't specifically forbidden in the question, either :)

Comment: @Mazura If you're going to stretch the definition of "spell" to include non-English spellings, then why not just use I? 10 is IIIIIIIIII for example. Then apply an encoding of zero and negative numbers so I is 0, II is 1, III is -1, IIII is 2, IIIII is -2, IIIIII is 3, ...

Comment: I is 1, II is 2. rotating 90° I is minus. Just one letter.

Comment: This seems *really* ambiguous, and the variety of answers seem to support this. What exactly does it mean to "spell any integer in English"?

Comment: I can do with zero letters, by simply using digits and minus sign instead, in the usual way. ;-)

Comment: I would suggest an edit that changes "spell" to "write"

Comment: "MINUS ONE" is not a number, because "minus" indicates subtraction.  He could say "ONE MINUS ONE MINUS ONE" etc. and get the result of "negative one", however.

Comment: If you were to consider each segment of a seven-segment display to be a single line (represented by the letter I), you could make any number, positive or negative, using just one letter. Throw in a dot for decimals and you're still only up to two "things".

Comment: @MontyHarder `MINUS ONE` indicates `-1`. The vast majority of Mathematicians and users of the English language would agree on that.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what it means to "spell" an integer. I could just use the English words "A" and "I", and encode any number in binary. Do you mean the resulting integer encoding is some sort of instruction to follow to generate the integer?

Comment: @GManNickG Well, I think if I encoded a number that way, I would also need additional instructions to explain how my encoding works, and I'd probably need more than two unique characters to spell those instructions. By spelling I just mean "writing with letters".

Comment: I'm closing as "too broad" since the validity of many of the answers seems to be opinion-based. There's no way to find an objectively correct best answer.

Comment: @Deusovi why not use the "correctness of the answers is opinion-based" close reason?

Comment: How would you do this in French?

Answer (score 43):

```
  ...
-3: MINUS ONE MINUS ONE MINUS ONE
-2: MINUS ONE MINUS ONE
-1: MINUS ONE
 0: ONE MINUS ONE
 1: ONE 
 2: ONE MINUS MINUS ONE
 3: ONE MINUS MINUS ONE MINUS MINUS ONE
    ...
```

two letters fewer since we do not use PLUS any more.

Comment: +1 Was about to post this when I read the question, but you beat me to it a few hours ago.

Comment: Is this considered unambiguous? For example, the expression `1 - - 1` would generally not be considered valid (but `1 - (-1)` would).

Comment: @svick I think there's only one interpretation possible of `ONE MINUS MINUS ONE`: `1 - (-1)`

Comment: You do have to be careful that ONE MINUS MINUS ONE MINUS MINUS ONE isn't misheard as $1 - (-1 - -1)$, but I think that's doable.

Comment: I think $a-b-c$ is well defined as $(a-b)-c$ (grouped left to right).

Comment: @Kos Not generally considered true; actually, by the standards of most programming languages, it is true; by the standard of mathematics, it is undefined. (In general, $a \operatorname{op}_1 b \operatorname{op}_2 c$ is well defined only if $\operatorname{op}_1$, $\operatorname{op}_2$ have defined precedence or if the operations are mutually associative within the given context, i.e. if it doesn't matter which operation you perform first.)

Comment: @yo' No, I think Kos is right. Writing $a-b-c$ is acceptable and is interpreted as $(a-b)-c$ even if this may not necessarily be true for operations other than subtraction.

Comment: @QuestionAsker "right" for the use in an answer to a puzzle? Quite sure. Right for general use without explanation, remark or even a definition? Not so quite. If I was to review a math paper and it used this, I would ask for clarification.

Comment: @yo' Surely we assume BODMAS (or BIDMAS, etc) whenever we write something like that. It says we apply the operations in the order specified and from left to right. Since we have two of the same operation here, we apply it from left to right and get $(a-b)-c$?

Comment: @QuestionAsker Sorry, I'm a mathematician; the "only" assumption I make is that the axioms are consistent. All the rest is a matter of definitions and proofs.

Comment: @yo' So am I... although I'm happy to follow widely accepted definitions. :) I see your point, however, and it does emphasize the necessity for rigorous definitions and notation to eliminate all ambiguity.

Comment: I know this isn't english.stackexchange.com, but it the phrase really is `two letters fewer`

Comment: The words "minus" and "negative" are not the same thing. There is no number "minus one"; only "negative one".  "Minus" refers to the process of subtracting a number from another number.

Comment: @MontyHarder Yeah, but it's English, a strange and fuzzy language that's generally disconnected from technical correctness, and if you went up to somebody on the street and said "minus one" you'd put a "-1" in their head, which is the correct result. Do it enough times and we'd eventually just update our dictionaries, ha. At least this answer is one that doesn't need further explanation, most of the other answers use these strange encodings that you couldn't just *say* to somebody without giving them the full background first.

Answer (score 25):

> 4 letters: `E N O T`

Explanation:

> My idea is to use binary and [marcoresk's idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42346/what-is-the-smallest-set-of-letters-that-can-spell-any-integer/42348#42348) of using `NOT` to represent the `-` sign, although I have to admit it might be slightly 'cheating' as I have to define things and work in a different base.
>  To represent a number you read out its binary representation using `ONE` and `NONE` to represent $1$s and $0$s.
>  Eg. $5$ would be: `ONE NONE ONE`
> If the number is negative, add a `NOT` to the beginning.
>  Eg. $-6$ would be: `NOT ONE ONE NONE`

Extension:

> You can represent any decimal which is terminating in binary with an extra letter `D` for a total of 5 letters which allows you to say `DOT` for the decimal point.
>  Eg. $-5.5$ would be: `NOT ONE NONE ONE DOT ONE`

Other possibilities:

> I understand that using `NOT` probably isn't the best idea to indicate `-`, so as I've mentioned in the comments, perhaps `NEG` can be used instead as it's an abbreviation for negative (I wasn't sure of this until Jason C pointed it out in [his answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42346/what-is-the-smallest-set-of-letters-that-can-spell-any-integer/42404#42404)). This will still result in 4 letters being used (although 6 for the extension).

Comment: You could define a negative bit and get rid of the T

Comment: I think `NOT x` should be interpreted as `-x-1` rather than `-x`.

Comment: @R.. Positive: `~x` is `-(x+1)`, not `-x`.

Comment: I would think `NOT` is `0` or `FALSE`, not `-`

Comment: Well — I was only putting a suggestion for defining `NOT` which sort of makes sense. I wasn't thinking about the actual Boolean definition. Would `NEG` work for negative instead?

Comment: Of course, I could just take Jonathan Allan's idea of having the first bit represent the sign like computer data which would use only 3 letters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intent of the question was that the meaning would be clear by some ordinary interpretation of the natural-language words used, not whether you could somehow encode meaning in the letters where it would require knowledge of your scheme to interpret. Otherwise the answer is obviously one: express an enumeration of the integers in base-one.

Comment: There is precedent for the word "not", as an arithmetic operator, to have "not x" mean "-x-1". I can't think of any other meaning you could reasonably expect it to have if applied to integers and not booleans; certainly a definition that yields "not zero = zero" is not reasonable.

Comment: I don't understand how your definitions make sense, though. Could you provide a link? If I plug 0 or 1 (which usually represent `TRUE`/`FALSE` in Boolean) I don't get the other?

Comment: I could also use Ali Humayun's idea of using `OFF` as subtraction. So for any negative numbers I would say: 'the magnitude' OFF NONE. This would keep the 4 letter total.

Comment: Dot one means ".5"?

Comment: If we're using binary and iffy definitions, why not just use "on" for 1 and "no" for 0, then you could do the whole thing in 2 letters.  Keeping in mind he said "Integer" so we don't need a decimal point.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Yes. The $n$th place after the decimal represents $2^{-n}$. It was just an extension which I thought I might add because it used only one more letter.

Comment: People read "101" as "one o one". Why not replace "none" by "o"? Same amount of distinct letters, just shorter ;)

Comment: @R.. "not x" = "-x-1" is two's complement binary numbers. In one's complement "not x" =  "-x".

Comment: @Johnbot: The naming is deceiving because it makes it sound like "twos complement" is something special. Rather it's just "math" as opposed to "some engineer's wacky idea". :-) This is reflected in the fact that the bitwise operators in C are not really well-defined for signed operands on (purely theoretical) non-twos-complement implementations (complex topic and probably off-topic here).

Answer (score 15):

If we use `LESS` to indicate subtraction, then we have

-1 = `ONE LESS ONE LESS ONE`

0 = `ONE LESS ONE`

1 = `ONE`

2 = `ONE PLUS ONE`

etc., using only seven letters `ELNOPSU`.

Comment: What about using punctuation? Say "ONE LESS: ONE LESS  ONE LESS ONE" as 2 (1 less -1). That gets you to 5 letters. Or 6 if you count the colon, which you really shouldn't.

Comment: @Hugh Punctuation strikes me as cheating.

Comment: I don't think you need punctuation; it's clear enough that "less" is being used as an operation.

Comment: @Samthere "Less" is indeed being used as an operation -- I agree with you there. But Hugh's intended solution needs to distinguish between 1-1-1-1 = -2 and 1-(1-1-1) = 2. The 4 operands and 3 operations are the same in the two cases. But they are grouped in different ways in order to get different results. And it's the proposed means to do that which struck me as cheating.

Comment: @RosieF Oh, I see what you mean; Hugh's suggestion is for using your subtraction operator to achieve positive numbers instead of having an addition operator. I agree that it's cheating, or rather that to do it in the spirit of the question would require you to write "OPEN BRACKET" "CLOSE BRACKET" or something similar.

Answer (score 13):

If any integer can be spelled with this structure

one **some operation** one **some operation** one

the trick could be simply this: reduce the numbers of letters needed for operations (or use O, N, E as much as you can!).

M,I,N,U,S introduces 4 new letters (N does not count)
P,L,U,S introduces 2 other letters (P and L)

A simple (but symbolic) solution is to represent a *operation* with a single letter... but this is not a way to "say it in English".

So I propose this structure:
PLUS becomes AND (only two more letters, A and D).
Every integer number N bigger than 1 can be said as

```
N =  ONE AND ONE AND ONE AND ONE...
```

B) Define the number MINUS ONE as "NOT ONE" (let's say this will became our convention, this is the weakest part!) in order to introduce only one more letter (T)

Now zero becomes

```
ZERO =  ONE AND (NOT ONE)
```

C) Since every negative numbers is equal to its absolute value multiplied by -1
e.g. -59 = 59 * (-1)
I suggest to use a new word to introduce the operation of multiplication, as in class we often say A multiplied by B as "A dot B" (A dot is one possible symbol to show multiplication in advanced math, instead of x or * or others)

Note that now DOT does not introduce any new letter. 
So -3 could be

```
(ONE AND ONE AND ONE) DOT (NOT ONE)
```

Notice we have used **only 6 letters** instead of 9 (and mantaining a speakable structure) O, N , E, D, T, A

Now the last problem: how to "say" parenthesis? With the rithm of speech!
ONE AND ONE AND ONE AND ONE [*after this sequence do a little pause*] DOT [*say DOT as an important word, then a little pause*] NOT ONE [*say NOT ONE fast, as if would be a single word*]

Thank you for this pretty puzzle and sorry for my poor english!

Comment: How about defining `NOT` as an operator which multiplies by -1? You wouldn't need `DOT` in C), although it doesn't make a difference to the letter count.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: @QuestionAsker your doubt is right, thank you for asking. I made this choice basically because i wanted to force my answer to be "the more speakable" as possible (it was the request after all). And introducing the DOT I didn't add any letter, so I preferred a longer but more understandable (I hope!) solution

Comment: Why not have `ZERO = NONE`?

Comment: @SQB I mainly use the zero to exemplify the NOT operator, needed for negative integers, and simply because the using of NONE does not reduce the 6 letters ;)

Answer (score 9):

Since

> "O" is in the [Collins English dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/o_1#o_1__32) as "used to mean zero"
>  (pronounced the same as "owe", as in "I **owe** MackTuesday a coconut")
>
>  ...and, as pointed out by @MackTuesday, "a" means one
>  (as in "I owe MackTuesday **a** coconut")

We can

> Use just **two** letters: O, and a
>  (I previously used three with One rather than a, which may be less confusing)
>
>  If we use base 2, or binary with a [signed magnitude representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method) by using our first bit as an indication of "is this number negative" and the time we stop speaking to represent our most significant bit for example:
>  $-32 =$ a O O O O O a $=- (0\times 2^0 + 0\times 2^1 + 0\times 2^2 + 0\times 2^3 + 0\times 2^4 + 1\times 2^5)$
>
>  $-7 =$ a a a a
>  $=- (1\times 2^0 + 1\times 2^1 + 1\times 2^2)$
>
>  $-4 =$ a O O a
>  $=- (0\times 2^0 + 0\times 2^1 + 1\times 2^2)$
>
>  $0 =$ O O (or a O)
>  $=+ (0\times 2^0)$ (or $=- (0\times 2^0)$)
>
>  $17 =$ O a O O O a
>  $=+ (0\times 2^0 + 0\times 2^1 + 0\times 2^2 + 0\times 2^3 + 1\times 2^4)$

Note that

> $2^n$ just means $2$ multiplied by itself $n$ times, so $2^3$ is $2\times 2 \times 2=8$
>  ...and that the identity element of the multiplication group is $1$ so $2^0$ is $2$ multiplied by itself $0$ times, [which must be $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9718/227125).

Comment: Could you get away with using `I` for one? :p

Comment: @QuestionAsker I thought about it, and it is in Collins but with the parenthesised prefix "Roman numeral", so I'm not so sure.

Comment: The article "a" is also used to mean 1, as in "a banana".

Comment: @MackTuesday your solid grasp of English must be unsurpassed, who knows such obscure words?! I updated the answer; thank you!

Comment: I think this stretches OP's wording of what it means to spell something too far.

Comment: @user1717828 which is exactly why I left the note in about using $3$ with `O,n,e`.

Answer (score 9):

6 Letters: T I M E S U

> -1: i times i 
>   0: sum i i times i times i
>   1: i times i times i times i
>   2: sum i times i times i times i i times i times i times i
>   3: sum i times i times i times i i times i times i times i i times i times i times i
>   -2: i times i times sum i times i times i times i i times i times i times i

*i* being the mathematical constant for the square root of -1. *i* squared ("i times i") is -1 and *i* to the fourth power ("i times i times i times i") is 1.

If the pause between the items in the set it not clear enough, you could also use the notation: 
3: sum **set** **item** i times i times i times i **item** i times i times i times i **item** i times i times i times i

Comment: Wow, nice idea!

Comment: You could also use `T` `I` `M` `E` `S` `L` to spell `LESS` instead of `SUM`. And you could write 0 less verbosely as $i + i^3$ (*sum i i times i times i*). Other than that, +1.

Comment: @GOTO0 good point, edited for the 0 calculation

Answer (score 8):

Another way of using only **seven** letters (A, D, E, L, N, O, S):

```
    ...
-3: ONE LESS ONE LESS ONE LESS ONE LESS ONE
-2: ONE LESS ONE LESS ONE LESS ONE
-1: ONE LESS ONE LESS ONE
 0: ONE LESS ONE
 1: ONE
 2: ONE AND ONE
 3: ONE AND ONE AND ONE
 4: ONE AND ONE AND ONE AND ONE
    ...
```

Comment: For a moment there I thought you were spelling my name

Answer (score 8):

> ONE ON ONE = 2
>
> ONE OFF ONE = 0

ONEF: total 4 letters

by replacing plus and minus with on and off which mean the same.

Comment: How and why do on and off mean the same as plus and minus?!?

Comment: @curiousdannii If you take one dollar off your bank account balance you have one less dollar in your bank account; if you put one on it you have one more dollar there; if your balance is, at some point, zero and you take one off you are in debt by a dollar.

Comment: @Jonathan I know how to count, but in English "one off one" is not the same as "one minus one". "One off one" does not have any idiomatic meaning.

Comment: @curiousdannii well I'd understand it (I'm English too)

Comment: in idiomatic terms one wouldn't call  one plus one instead of two at the first place

Comment: For the minus, this would be different: `x OFF y` is `y - x`.

Comment: but the letters would remain same

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος True, but when `x==y` then it doesn't matter.

Comment: yes but it still doesn't matter in this particular case.

Answer (score 5):

If we are allowed any encoding we like, we only need one letter. We choose some way of enumerating integers (say, in the order 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3 ...) and then we encode the $n^\mathrm{th}$ integer as $n$ repetitions of our letter.

I don't think this is in the spirit of the question, which means that many of the other answers also aren't in the spirit of the question ("spell any integer *in English*"; I interpret this to mean, if you need to *explain* what number you are spelling, you have already lost). But if you're going to give an unspirited answer, you might as well give the optimal one :)

Comment: Hurrah for unary notation! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The rules to this seem a little ambiguous but does this count? 4 letters:

> {O,N,E,G}
>
>  Where all positive integers are just a that many ones:
>  1: one
>  2: one one
>  3: one one one
>
>  And negative integers are indicated by ["neg"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/neg) (an English abbreviation):
>  -1: neg one
>  -2: neg one one
>  -3: neg one one one
>
>  And zero is just an o:
>  0: o

Comment: what are you doing down here? lol

Answer (score 3):

5 (O N E L S)

For example:
110=ONE ONE ONE LESS ONE=111-1
Just do the lowest integer above your target value consisting of only ones, then subtract down. Works for any positive or negative number.

Answer (score 1):

2 answer depends on the rule

> write numbers in binary representation (9 letters o,n,e,z,r,m,i,u,s)
>  1 = one
>  -1 = minus one
>  0  = zero
>  2 = one zero

or

> or maybe just 6 letters (m,i,n,u,s,o) if we can write 1 as i and 0 as o
> (maybe invalid)
>  1 = i
>  -1 = minus i
>  0  = o
>  2 = io

Answer (score 1):

We can refer to the number 1 using the less common word [`UNIT`](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unit). Using `MINUS` adds two letters. Then using the word [`SUM`](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sum) in place of `PLUS` adds no new letters. Unlike `PLUS`, which is an operation between two operands, `SUM` naturally operates on all following operands.

```
-3: MINUS SUM UNIT UNIT UNIT
-2: MINUS SUM UNIT UNIT
-1: MINUS UNIT
 0: UNIT MINUS UNIT
 1: UNIT
 2: SUM UNIT UNIT
 3: SUM UNIT UNIT UNIT
```

If you're unhappy with the `SUM` operator taking an arbitrary number of operands, we can have it apply to only two operands. I've summarised below, using [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) for both `SUM x y`=x+y and `MINUS x y`=x-y.

```
-3: MINUS UNIT SUM SUM SUM UNIT UNIT UNIT UNIT
-2: MINUS UNIT SUM SUM UNIT UNIT UNIT
-1: MINUS UNIT SUM UNIT UNIT
 0: MINUS UNIT UNIT
 1: UNIT
 2: SUM UNIT UNIT
 3: SUM SUM UNIT UNIT UNIT
```

Thus we have **6 unique letters:** `IMNSTU`

Answer (score 0):

Five letters: `{Z, E, R, O, N}`

No maths required, but you have to understand binary.  We spell out the bits involved in a binary representation of the desired integer.  The first bit is the sign bit (`ZERO` for positive, `ONE` for negative).

Examples:

```
-3: ONE ONE ONE
-2: ONE ONE ZERO
-1: ONE ONE
 0: ZERO ZERO
 1: ZERO ONE 
 2: ZERO ONE ZERO
 3: ZERO ONE ONE
```

Comment: The idea here seems to be similar to that of [Question Asker's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42359/5373), but using 5 letters instead of 4.

Comment: Or, on the topic of using 0 and 1 as signs, you could just represent 0 as NONE, hence *three* characters! `NONE ONE ONE = -2` for example. edit: should I make this a community wiki answer? :P

Comment: Or even use  `O` instead of `ZERO` so you can remove `Z` & `R`

Comment: The phrase "no maths required, but you have to understand binary" has me scratching my head :)

Comment: Question Asker's answer uses a special prefix to indicate negative numbers; this one uses two's complement, forcing the extra bit. That makes it different enough IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I used only **SUB**  instead of **PLUS** and **MINUS**.

Using only **six** letters **(B, E, N, O, U, S)**:

> -3 : SUB (ONE ONE ONE)
>
> -2 : SUB (ONE ONE)
>
> -1 : SUB (ONE ONE)
>
> 0 : (ONE SUB ONE)
>
> 1 : SUB (SUB ONE)
>
> 2 : SUB (SUB ONE SUB ONE)
>
> 3 : SUB (SUB ONE SUB ONE)

Comment: Your answer relies on additional punctuation to avoid ambiguity, which feels like it's outside of the scope of good answers. Not a bad idea but it relies on interpreting or encoding language as well; we can obviously recognise the intended meaning of "sub" but it isn't standard.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at all the number in binary give use the word zero and One which results in 5 characters.

8 = 1000 = one zero zero zero.

15 = 1111 = one one one one.

Comment: How is your answer any different from the ones already posted here before you? In addition you don't deal with the negative cases.