# Create a rule, so every integer can be written in only 1 symbol

Tags: pattern, information-theory

Inspired from [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42346/what-is-the-smallest-set-of-letters-that-can-spell-any-integer)

Create a mathematic rule, so every integer can be written in only 1 symbol.

Note : white spaces (space, tab, etc) is considered as different symbol

Comment: Soooo you're asking for a bijection between the sets N and Z.

Comment: I could write every integer using a dotty font. Only one symbol is used — the dots.

Comment: Kind of unary I think then????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\triangle \to 0$
$\triangle\triangle \to 1$
$\triangle\triangle\triangle \to -1$
$\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle \to 2$
$\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle \to -2$
$\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle \to 3$
$\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle \to -3$
$\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle \to 4$
$\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle\triangle \to -4$
...

Comment: How it works: $△$ is $0$. For other integers, if $n_△ mod 2=0$, then $n=n_△/2$. If $n_△ mod 2=1$, then the result is $n=-\lfloor n_△/2\rfloor$.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Or $n=(-1)^{n_△}\lfloor n_△/2\rfloor$, if you are lazy :)